# Merging two layers and assign ID of bigger polygons to smaller polygons within bigger

Tags: qgis, layers, merge, within

I am basically new to QGIS and want to use spatial data to get the state identifiers for small polygons (say counties/zip areas) which are geographically inside the bigger polygons (states/cities). The problem is that counties layer does not have the ids (or the same ids) as the state (bigger) layer (otherwise I could just merge csv files). I tried MMQGIS merge tool but it seems that this tool can’t merge the data if there is no common identifier for both layers, just based on their geographical properties (one polygon being inside of the other).

Comment: Try the ["Join attributes by location"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#join-attributes-by-location), here is a tutorial: https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/performing_spatial_joins.html

Comment: Yes I tried that and it works! My problem was essentially deeper —I’ve had python conflicts so I didn’t have all functionality and even “join attributes...” After resolving python issues I downloaded 3.8 old version of QGIS and everything seems to work. Thanks!